# Woocommerce how to format the billing address in the order email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, woocommerce-email

How can I format the billing address in the order email to be clear?

I need to display the followings:

- City: {billing_city}
- Street: {billing_street}
- and so on.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy Woocommerce email template files to your theme (if you dont have them) or edit existing ones in your template.
Template file names are:

template_name/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php 
template_name/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php 
template_name/woocommerce/emails/email-addresses.php

Here you can customize the email template as you wish.

For example in email/email-adresses.php by default billing information code part look like this:

```
<td style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border:0; padding:0;" valign="top" width="50%">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

            <address class="address">
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( $address ? $address : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
                <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
                    <br/><?php echo wc_make_phone_clickable( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                    <br/><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </address>
    </td>
```

So you can customize and add/remove all information you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to make the address to be clear in all emails Can you please help?

Comment: @MohamedBadawy if you customize these templates, they will be clear in all emails.

Comment: I opened the 2 files that you mentioned from /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails    but I can't find anything related to the billing address

Comment: @MohamedBadawy updated, my answer, please have a look. Besides, all email files in woocommerce/emails folder is useful for customization.

Comment: Can you please clarify which part I will need to edit?  Thanks,

Comment: <address class="address">
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $address ? $address : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
    <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
     <br/><?php echo wc_make_phone_clickable( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
     <br/><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?>
     
    <?php endif; ?>
   </address>

Comment: @MohamedBadawy have you copied this files to your template and edit there?

Comment: I edited the email address only and in its existing place

Comment: I added  <?php echo "City" + esc_html( $order->get_billing_city() ); ?>  and for each field just change the name afyer get_billing

Comment: Not working I added the following:                                                                                                   <?php echo"Region: " +esc_html( $order->get_billing_state() ); ?>
     <?php echo"Area: " + esc_html( $order->get_billing_city() ); ?>
     <?php echo"Street: " + esc_html( $order->get_billing_address_2() ); ?>
     <?php echo"Block: " + esc_html( $order->get_billing_address_1() ); ?>